# jQuery on keyboard function fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first time it runs smooth but when I repeat the proccess it fires two times adding 2 fields instead of one per Shift+Enter, could anyone explain me why and offer a solution?

```
$(document).on('click', "span.adbt", function () {
    $('.caddtask').toggleClass('inactive').html("<span class='tfields'><textarea autofocus placeholder='Shift+Enter adds another field' maxlength='30' class='tinput n1' /></span><span class='add'></span>").css({
        'height': '52px'
    });
    $('.add').click(function () {
        SaveTask(date)
    });
    $(document).on('keypress', "textarea.tinput", function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey && $('.tinput:last-of-type').attr('class').slice(-1) < 4) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.tfields').append("<textarea autofocus maxlength='30' class='tinput n" + (Number($('.tinput:last-of-type').attr('class').slice(-1)) + 1) + "' />");
            $('.caddtask').css({
                'height': '+=44'
            });
            $('.add').css({
                'top': '+=22'
            });
        }
    });
});

function SaveTask(date) {
    var fields = $('.tinput:last-of-type').attr('class').slice(-1);
    if (Day[date.dayOfYear()].tasks == '') $('.tlist').html('');
    for (var i = 1; i <= fields; i++) {
        if ($('.n' + i).val() === '') {
            $('.tinput').attr('placeholder', 'Enter a task here');
            return;
        }
        if (tasks.length > 0) {
            var id = tasks.length;
            tasks[id] = {
                id: tasks[(id - 1)].id + 1,
                belongs: Number(String(2014).slice(2, 4).concat('00'.concat(date.dayOfYear()).slice(-3))),
                status: false,
                text: $('.n' + i).val()
            };
            $('.tlist').append("<li class='id" + tasks[id].id + "'><span class='status false'></span><span class='tasktext'>" + tasks[id].text + "</span></li>");
        } else {
            var id = 0; 
            tasks[0] = {
                id: 0,
                belongs: Number(String(2014).slice(2, 4).concat('00'.concat(date.dayOfYear()).slice(-3))),
                status: false,
                text: $('.tinput').val()
            };
            $('.tlist').html("<li class='id" + tasks[0].id + "'><span class='status false'></span><span class='tasktext'>" + tasks[0].text + "</span></li>");
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
    $('.caddtask').toggleClass('inactive').html("<span class='adbt'>Add task</span>");
    $('.add').css({
        'top': '14px'
    });
    $('.inactive').css({
        'height': '26px'
    });
};
```

And why does it stop autofocusing the textearea on it's 2nd execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your Problem**

Assigning event handlers inside other event handlers.
This will assign the event handlers on each click on `span.adbt`.
Hence, you get multiple execution of handlers, which will be twice on your second click like you said.

**Solution**

Keep your event handlers separate...

It should be:

```
$(document).on('click', "span.adbt", function () {
    $('.caddtask').toggleClass('inactive').html("<span class='tfields'><textarea autofocus placeholder='Shift+Enter adds another field' maxlength='30' class='tinput n1' /></span><span class='add'></span>").css({
        'height': '52px'
    });
});
$('.add').on('click',function () {
    SaveTask(date);
});
$(document).on('keypress', "textarea.tinput", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && e.shiftKey && $('.tinput:last-of-type').attr('class').slice(-1) < 4) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.tfields').append("<textarea autofocus maxlength='30' class='tinput n" + (Number($('.tinput:last-of-type').attr('class').slice(-1)) + 1) + "' />");
        $('.caddtask').css({
            'height': '+=44'
        });
        $('.add').css({
            'top': '+=22'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Use event delegation for `.add`, Notice `.html("<span class='tfields'><textarea autofocus placeholder='Shift+Enter adds another field' maxlength='30' class='tinput n1' /></span><span class='add'></span>")`

Comment: Yes, was just editting it... :) `.add` delegation was added in the edit as well :D

Comment: I see, thanks. This seems better than the .one solution. Maybe you also know why it stops autofocusing the field the 2nd time?

Comment: @Dooderino The `.one` solution would be just a workaround. Else this can surely cause problems. And to focus textarea, you can use `$(".tinput").focus()` after appending it in HTML. Try it out...